# awk printing with and without {}?

Tags: awk

I have sample data

```
Person  Owe
John    1
John    2
John    -1
John    -10
John    5
John    9
John    -4
John    9
John    2
John    3
```

I was using script file to parse this and the command is
`awk -f script data`
, script content:

```
NR == 2 { print "Starting Here"; x = $2; next}
{x+= $2} #This x+=$2
END{ print x }
```

Output:

```
Starting Here
16
```

But when I remove `{}` from `{x+=$2}`
Output:

```
Starting Here
John    2
John    -1
John    -10
John    5
John    9
John    -4
John    9
John    2
John    3
16
```

Q) Why does it print if I don't have a `{}` around the variable addition?

Comment: I think you should read awk manual.

Comment: Click on the awk tag above, then click "Learn more..." to learn more about awk.

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes, the answer is present there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering own question:

A rule needs an action. If action is missing it defaults to printing the line.
Just mentioning `x+=$2` is a rule, And if we give `{x+=$2}` or `x+=$2{}` those have/are action.

Comment: The default action only happens if the condition is **true**. If x is 5 and then $2 is -5, then x+=$2 results in zero (a false value), and that line will not be printed.